# IBM Websphere Message Broker and Mule ESB

Tags: esb, ibm-integration-bus, mule-esb

I'm currently using Mule ESB which is an open source tool.  It has the MuleStudio (graphical IDE) for developers.  I think IBM WebSphere Message Broker is also an ESB product.  By reading the required products from IBM website, you need to have IBM developer tool, IBM Message Broker Message V7 and IBM MQ.  Does anyone know that these products free to developers or do we need to purchase them?  Has anyone migrate from Mule ESB to IBM Message Broker V7? Are the Mule ESB and IBM WS MB compatible in functionality?

Answer (score 0):

IBM Message Broker or as it called now **IBM Integration Bus Advanced**, have a fully licensed product available for download at no charge for developers.

You can find it here:
http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/integration-bus-advanced

Comment: Thanks Carleson!  I will download.